# Jackson in Jersey with multiple Serializers for one Entity

Tags: java, json, serialization, jersey, jackson

I'm implementing a REST backend with Jersey 2.11 and Jackson 2.4.0 for serialization.
My entity looks like this:

```
public class Measurement {

public Measurement() {
    super();
}

private Long id;
private Double lat;
private Double lon;
private Long timestamp;
private User owner;
}
```

In some responses I'd like this entity serialized as GeoJSON and in others as Measurement with the User.id instead of the User object. Therefore I wrote two custom JsonSerializers and registered them in my ObjectMapperResolver class.

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

private final ObjectMapper defaultMapper;
private final ObjectMapper geojsonMapper;

public ObjectMapperResolver() {
    defaultMapper = createDefaultMapper();
    geojsonMapper = createGeojsonMapper();
}

private static ObjectMapper createDefaultMapper() {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(Measurement.class, new MeasurementSerializer());

    return new ObjectMapper()
    .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
    .registerModule(module);
}

private static ObjectMapper createGeojsonMapper() {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(Measurement.class, new GeoJSONSerializer());

    return new ObjectMapper()
    .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
    .registerModule(module);
}

@Override
public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
    if (type.equals(Measurement.class)) {
        return geojsonMapper;
    }
    else {
        return defaultMapper;
    }
}
```

}

In the current setup whenever a Measurement is serialized its serialized as GeoJSON. Whenever my other entities (which do contain Measurements) are serialized the defaultMapper is used. *I'd need a possibility to switch Serializer/Mapper for one single entity class (Measurement.class)*

Best regards!

Comment: It is easy to achieve if you can have different media types for different formats.

Comment: Unfortunately my angular frontend prefers to deal with JSON only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did in my spring application:
1. Created my CustomObjectMapper classes.
2. Created class specific json generator methods.
3. Autowired required object mapper in the controller.

Mapper1:

```
public class CustomObjectMapper1 extends ObjectMapper {
    public CustomObjectMapper1() {
        super();
        super.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS);
        super.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
        super.setDateFormat(df);
    }
    public byte[] generateJson(Object value) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException {
        Hibernate4Module hm = new Hibernate4Module();
        hm.configure(Hibernate4Module.Feature.USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION, false);
        hm.configure(Hibernate4Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING, false);
        return super.registerModule(hm).writeValueAsBytes(value);
    }
}
```

Mapper2:

```
public class CustomObjectMapper2 extends ObjectMapper {
    public CustomObjectMapper2() {
        super();
        super.setDateFormat(df);
    }
    public byte[] generateJson(Object value) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException {
        Hibernate4Module hm = new Hibernate4Module();
        return super.registerModule(hm).writeValueAsBytes(value);
    }
}
```

In controller:

```
...
byte[] json = customObjectMapper1.generateJson(myObject);
return json;

...
byte[] json = customObjectMapper2.generateJson(myObject);
return json;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I like your solution and will probably use it. The only downside is that every response has to be serialized manually.